# Error using lodash.clonedeep in Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, lodash

First, I have never used lodash.clonedeep before but know JavaScript fairly well.

From my package,json file:
    "lodash.clonedeep": "4.5.0",

```
import { cloneDeep } from 'lodash.clonedeep';

editStart(): void {
   this.oldData = cloneDeep(this.currentData);
   this.editing = true;
}
```

Error: ERROR TypeError: lodash_clonedeep_1.cloneDeep is not a function

Help very MUCH appreciated since I'm out of options, have read and tried a lot of options. I have a workaround, using several objects, but want to avoid if possible.

Comment: Can you show us your package.json??

Comment: Your sintax is ok, you only need to change the . for  /, and use camelCase like this `'lodash/cloneDeep'`

Answer (score 12):

Your import statement is incorrect.

You should either import the full library:

```
import * as _ from 'lodash';
...
let foo = _.cloneDeep(bar);
```

Or import just the cloneDeep function:

```
import * as cloneDeep from 'lodash/cloneDeep';
...
let foo = cloneDeep(bar);
```

Answer (score 2):

My experience on the Angular 7:

When use in src project:

```
import * as cloneDeep from "lodash/cloneDeep";
```

When use in library project:

```
import cloneDeep from "lodash/cloneDeep";
```

Note: Better import per-module to decrease main module size ([the-correct-way-to-import-lodash-libraries-a-benchmark](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-correct-way-to-import-lodash-libraries-a-benchmark/)).